# Displaying coordinates of a Marker as it is being move

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to figure out how to get the coordinates of the marker1 to show in my element 'map-msg' as it is being move as part of my interaction.

```
    var coord1 = [-9807673.76, 3899420.81];

    var marker1 = new ol.geom.Point(coord1);
    var featureMarker1 = new ol.Feature(marker1);

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [featureMarker1]
      }),
      
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }), vector],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: coord1,
        zoom: 5
      })
    });

    var translate1 = new ol.interaction.Translate({
      features: new ol.Collection([featureMarker1])
    });
    map.addInteraction(translate1);
```

This function works fine to show my mouse pointer. How ever I would like to display the marker instead.

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  var coords = ol.proj.toLonLat(e.coordinate);
  var lat = coords[1];
  var lon = coords[0];
  var locTxt = "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon;
  // coords is a div in HTML below the map to display
  document.getElementById('map-msg').innerHTML = locTxt;
});
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a style function on the feature which sets a label to the feature's coordinates  This example uses modify https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-icon-forked-n8qxyf?file=/main.js but it should work just as well with translate